# How can I know if 10385274000 fits into: NUMBER(10) for Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, types, maxlength

I been working the whole week to troubleshot a production error.

I have eventually got the the point where I can find the culprit record which is causing all the mess.

I've got the following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [BEA][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column
```

Eventuall from all the info I think this might be the wrong data, the system is trying to insert:

```
10385274000
```

Into a NUMBER(10)

How can I know if that value fits or no?

Thank you

**EDIT**

As per Michel Todd suggestion:

```
create table xyz( testfield number( 10 ) );

insert into xyz values( 10385274000 )


Error: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

Thank you guys!!!

Thank you stackoverflow

**EDIT**

Notes to my self ( not to forget what was the problem )

I had this Oracle product which stores in a database table the time of an event

```
START_TIME|END_TIME
```

It turns out everynight it backups this information into another table but performs a trnsformation in the process. It does store as:

```
TOTALTIME
```

The problem comes when this field is calculated by subtracting ENDTIME - STARTTIME. The resulting number is stored in this column which is defined as: **NUMBER(10)**

Well, it turns out if END_TIME-START_TIME are too far away in the time ( about 4 months or so ) the value ( in milliseconds ) would be SO big it won't fit in the target column ( I guess it has something like endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime() inside the code )

All this sounds too easy and too silly now, but it took me 4 day+ to find out, because since this is a closed application I didn't have a clue of what was happening, the only thing I've got was the stacktrace.

I had to reverse engineer ( in the OLD sense of the word, by hand and obviously with out the source) the entire process to find this out.

When I did it, I've got the same error in my "hand coded migrator" and find out how to solve it!

Comment: If you do use the word 'Urgent', please use it in a readable format instead of a ongoing word. If it is urgent it is urgent, but people have to know that it is urgent, which is hard when it is : "Urgeeeent!"

Comment: A q&d way to do it is to create a temp table containing a number(10) and trying to insert that value. It if it works, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number 10 in NUMBER(10) specifies the field size. That means that the field can hold a number up to 10 characters long. Your number has 11 digits and thus the value is to large to fit. Anything smaller than (<) 10 billion (10 000 000 000) can be inserted without trouble. That's what you need to check for if you want to validate the value before inserting.

Comment: Like if they were characters?

Comment: A quick Google gave this reference page: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/datatypes.php

Comment: The "10" in Number(10) specifies the total number of digits. Optionally, you can also specify the number of decimals. To quote the link above "For example, numeric(7,2) is a number that has 5 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal."

Comment: @Emil H -- Why not anything smaller than (99 999 999 999)?

Comment: @JohnOsborne: Because 10 000 000 000 and up to 99 999 999 999 has 11 digits.